# Qt and Webkit not showing all CSS 3, HTML 5 effects

Tags: c++, css, qt, webkit

I am a beginner. I am creating a web browser with Qt and webkit (simply added a webview). I am using the latest version of Ubuntu.

The problem is after builidng the browser, when I open websites there are not working all CSS3, HTML5 effects (ie: when I open Google maps then it shows "the simplified version" as because the browser is "outdated").

When I try to access the same pages with chrome or firefox all works well. What could be the problem? I read that I can update the webkit of Qt, but how?

EDIT

What is my software: a simple webview dragged to the mainwindow which opens a website. Website's CSS3 and HTML 5 are not rendered properly

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which Qt version are you using?

Comment: Maybe changing your user-agent?

Comment: @m.s. Qt Creator 3.3.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.1 (GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit)

Comment: @danielfranca how to change the user-agent? and how will make this rendering new css and html properly?

Comment: My guess is because of the message you get accessing Google Maps. You can try something like that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage.html#userAgentForUrl

Comment: I just tried it with Qt 5.3 (on Ubuntu 14.04), Google Maps works fine for me in a QWebView without any changes of useragent etc.

Comment: @m.s. thank you for your comment. I did a dist-upgrade but the problem is the same: http://s8.postimg.org/w6yhbpfol/error.png this is a screenshot

Comment: The user agent of mine is this: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) 0.1 Safari/538.1 when I am using my qt webview

Comment: ah, thanks for the screenshot, I thought the "lite mode" would look totally different than usual... I also have this message in my version if I click on the lightning symbol

Comment: When I open google.com it shows the older version too. Google images is horrible.

Comment: Does anyone know a method to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Google uses the user agent to decide whether your browser supports CSS3 features. You can override the default user agent to make your QWebView appear to Google like a Firefox instance, for example.

You need to subclass QWebPage and override the [`userAgentForUrl`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage.html#userAgentForUrl) method:

```
class WebPage : public QWebPage
{
public:
    WebPage(QObject* parent = 0) : QWebPage(parent){}
    QString userAgentForUrl(const QUrl &url) const
    {
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0";
    }
};
```

You then set this subclass into your QWebView:

```
WebPage* webPage = new WebPage(this);
ui->webView->setPage(webPage);
ui->webView->load(QUrl("http://maps.google.com/"));
```

Comment: One more related problem. At this moment there are some CSS effects which are not rendered properly. So, the problem is not entirely solved. Open this website: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ and click on the top-left menu. the menu icon will be converted (animated) to "X". This works in chrome, firefox, but not in my webview.

Comment: I checked the problem. There are some css conditions which aren't using the "-webkit" prefix. Thank you a lot for your help!